# GTM Track JQuery click event

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a page with this code:

```
<tr class="item" data-id="123" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <td>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="title">Title 1</div>
            <div class="description alpha">Description 1</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="price">25</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And a JQuery code like this:

```
$('.item').on('click', event => {
    const i = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
    location.href = Util.buildUrl('order') + '&i=' + i;
});
```

I'd like to know how can I track this click on Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `Click - All Elements` trigger choosing *This trigger fires on* `Some Clicks` adding `Click Classes` equals *item*.